# How to count and then vlookup?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two spreadsheets and I want to sum up the total and then vlookup but when I do it I get 0 as a result.
Basically I have all 12 weeks, so I want to sum up all the numbers for "week 1" then vlookup the total to the other spreadsheet. [the spreadsheet I want to sup up, so 7x10 = 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdvjG.png)
[image]

[the overview spreadsheet I want to get the "70" from week 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCuRZ.png)
[image]

Comment: This looks like a job for SUMIFS(), not VLOOKUP(). It's difficult to help you further not knowing if you have tables and without row and column coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Vlookup, because you have many values for week 1, and no identifier for the week 1 total. Instead, on the summary sheet, you can use a Sumif() or Sumifs() function. Something along the lines of this:

```
=Sumifs(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A3)
```

In words: Sum up all the values from Sheet1 in column C where column A in Sheet1 has the same value as cell A3 on Sheet2.

You need to adjust the sheet names and cell references to reflect your workbook.

With that approach, you do not need to enter weekly totals into your first sheet at all. It's not good practice to interrupt a table of data entry cells with formulas. It's better to do the reporting and analysis outside of the data entry table.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.